# Refresh Menu with invalidate in Android

Tags: android, menuitem

I am working on Android application in which I want to refresh my menu at run time. For example if in the starting my menu is like `menu1.xml` then after getting any result for example 'Yes' from the server I want to refresh it with `menu2.xml`.

I want to use invalidate function for this but I am not able to make my menu items to be refreshed. My code is given below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

    if (showAcceptButton==true) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
        return true;
    }if (Constants.showAcceptedButton = true) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
        return true;
    }
    if(showNormalMenu==true){
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu3, menu);
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

At onCreate for the first time it loads the menu but on run time I want to load another menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

It will give existing menu object and you can add or delete menu items from it.

**UPDATE:**

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    menu.clear();
    if (showAcceptButton==true) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
        return true;
    }if (Constants.showAcceptedButton = true) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
        return true;
    }
    if(showNormalMenu==true){
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu3, menu);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please write some example code according to my above description for example like if i get "Yes" then it will load another Menu Items.